# Angular 7 - How to deal with two different navbars based on window size?

Tags: css, angular, material-design, responsive

My question is quite simple I guess,

I'm at the beginning of a project, and I just finished the Sidenav (positionned to the left of the screen), which I actually use as a component. I want to use a "normal" top navbar when the window is smaller, but I don't know how to actually implement this. Do I need another component for the top navbar ? If so, how do I switch between those 2 based on window size ?

I use Materialize CSS by the way...

Comment: You could have 2 seperate components, unless they layout is simple to switch from a horizontal to a mobile-friendly vertical.  See the [material cdk](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. When I was creating a resume in Angular, I wanted to show `mat-horizontal-stepper` when the screen is larger than 700px, and `mat-vertical-stepper` when it is smaller than it. So I created a `HostListener` to `window:resize` event.

[This is my deployed resume, if you resize you can see the expected behavior.](https://thomazcapra.github.io/presentation/)

[This is how my `HTML` with `horizontalStepper`, at line 23 you can see that if the value is true show something, otherwise show something else.](https://github.com/thomazcapra/presentation/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html)

[And this is my component's TS file, at line 36 you can find the `HostListener`.](https://github.com/thomazcapra/presentation/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts)